# React.lazy & Suspence,Lazy loading component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lazy-loading

I was trying to create LLC https://blog.logrocket.com/lazy-loading-components-in-react-16-6-6cea535c0b52/ but eventually I got Error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, _ctor, _status, _result}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

```
<LazyLoadingComponent resolve={() => import('../StaticComponents/Notification/Notification')}>
</LazyLoadingComponent>
```

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

function LazyLoadingComponent({ resolve }) {
  console.log('resolve', resolve);
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={() => <h1>loading</h1>}>
      {lazy(async () => {
        const { default: module } = await resolve();
        console.log(module, 'module');
        return module;
      })}
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export default LazyLoadingComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
// App.js
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
// Import your compnent like so
const LazyComponent = lazy(() => import("./LazyComponent"))

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Testing Lazy component..</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<h2>See Loading?</h2>}>
        <LazyComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Your lazy component:**

```js
// LazyComponent.js
import React from "react";

export default function LazyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>I'm Lazy</h1>
      <p>
        This is my lazy component!
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

**[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-lazy-component-910db) example.**

Comment: Yeah,that's working fine,but I want to make it dynamic,for instance I pass in props path and than it falls into lazyComponent

Answer (score 0):

that works,anyway,thanks for help!

```
<LazyLoadingComponent
  component={lazy(() => import('../StaticComponents/Notification/Notification'))}
 ></LazyLoadingComponent>
```

```
    <Suspense fallback={() => <h1>loading</h1>}>
      <Component></Component>
    </Suspense>
```